# Add item to an array table colum during create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `quote` table column as array using postgres:

```
...

t.integer  "company_id", array: true, default: []

...
```

Essentially, I am saying is that a quote as many companies. It's like a tender so many business can bid on a quote.

**quote.rb:**

```
has_many :companies
```

Nothing is set in company.rb.

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :quotes
has_one :company # depending on registration type
```

The process is that a user can invite more than one companies to bid on a quote, in which their `company_id`, each, is passed as `params`. I can create the quote but the `company_id` is not saving:

```
def create
  company_id = 8 # hard coded for now
  @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params.push({:company_id => company_id}))

...
end

private
 def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:a, :b, :company_id => [])
 end
```

I can't push the `company_id` onto the quote. Ideas? Pic of the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Quote has many companies and a Company has many quotes? If that's true, then you have a N-to-N relation and you should have a relationship model.

This relationship model would be named CompanyQuote in lack of a better one, in your case seem you could use Bid. Then you would have to relate them.

```
class Quote
  has_many :bids
  has_many :companies, through: :bids
  # ...
end

class Company
  has_many :bids
  has_many :quotes, through: :bids
  # ...
end

class Bid
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :quote
  # ...
end

class QuotesController
  def create
    company_id = 8 # hard coded for now
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params.push({:company_ids => [company_id]}))

  ...
  end

  private

  def quote_params
   params.require(:quote).permit(:a, :b, :company_ids => [])
  end
end
```

Have a look in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Hi. I see. In that case, a client can choose x amount of companies to bid but how to assign those companies: `@quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params.push({:company_id => company_id}))`

Comment: In your controller you have to use it on the plural and in an array as that's a has_many relationship, like `{ company_ids => [8] }`.